# SQL query for fetching data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

hi i have a situation in sql as follows:

table name: `case_details`

```
caseid  refno   clientid   report_date

1       1/1     1007       08-05-2013
2       1/2     1007       01-06-2013  
3       1/3     1007       12-07-2013
4       1/4     1012       17-07-13 
5       1/6     1009       08-07-13
```

table name: `case_check_detail`

```
caseid    checkid   alert_val
1         1         1
1         2         2
1         3         1
1         4         2

2         5         4
2         6         3
2         7         2 
2         8         1

3         9         2
3         10        1
3         11        2
3         12        1

4         13        3
4         14        3
4         15        3
4         16        4

5         17        1
5         18        2
5         19        1
5         20        2
```

I want to count how many cases are there for `clientid` 1007 for whom the highest value of `alert_val` is 2 between 01-05-2013 to 18-07-2013

Like in this case its:

```
case id:1,caseid:3
```

Comment: maybe you could refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458364/fetch-data-with-single-and-fast-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT d.caseid
  FROM case_details d JOIN case_check_detail c
    ON d.caseid = c.caseid 
 WHERE d.clientid = 1007
   AND d.report_date BETWEEN '20130501' AND '20130718'
 GROUP BY d.caseid
HAVING MAX(c.alert_val) = 2
```

Output:

```
| CASEID |
----------
|      1 |
|      3 |
```

If you want to count them

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT d.caseid
    FROM case_details d JOIN case_check_detail c
      ON d.caseid = c.caseid 
   WHERE d.clientid = 1007
     AND d.report_date BETWEEN '20130501' AND '20130718'
   GROUP BY d.caseid
  HAVING MAX(c.alert_val) = 2
) q
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL |
---------
|     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afc98/13)** demo

Comment: op needs data having max of alert_val as 2. not less than or equal to 2.

Comment: @Praveen Agreed. Misread. Thanks for the input. The answer and sqlfiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM case_check_detail AS ccd
JOIN case_details AS cd ON cd.caseid=ccd.caseid
 WHERE alert_val=2 AND report_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-07-18'
```

Comment: this will return count as 7.. where as answer expected is 2